# How to group points by defined count and return a bounding box for each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a large table of very irregularly spaced points.  Given a user-defined bounding box, I would like to return rows of sub-bounding boxes that represent an equal number of points.  The shape of the sub-boxes does not matter, as long as all points in the user-defined bounding box are represented and counted.

This is the logic I'm trying to implement:

1. select all points where intersects user's bounding box.
2. order all points by x value
3. group ordered points where count <= 1000
4. return ST_Extent of each group.

I'm not really sure where to begin, since I don't have a lot of experience with SQL and PostGIS, but something like this...?

```
SELECT 
    ST_Extent(geom) as extent,
    c.count
FROM 
    xyz_master as x,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as count
        FROM
            xyz_master
    ) as c
WHERE
    c.count < 1000
GROUP BY
    extent
;
```

And, of course, Postgres responds with this:

```
ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
LINE 3:  ST_Extent(geom) as extent
```

I realize the subquery doesn't really make much sense, since it's just returning one row with a count of all points, but I have no idea where to begin.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you could use the row_number window function to group your ordered points in your subquery  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the table based on x, then create a different group for each 1000s. Using CEIL is one way to do it. Note that you have to replace in the following code the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, and srid provided by the user:

```
SELECT ST_EXTENT(t2.geom) extent, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
    SELECT t1.geom, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ST_X(t1.geom)) row_num
    FROM xyz_master t1
    WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, srid), t1.geom)
) t2
GROUP BY CEIL(t2.row_num / 1000.0);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, thank you.  I tested your query on a small scale version of our database and it does exactly what I'm looking for, although I did have to edit the `ORDER BY t1.x` clause since since the point geometry is a PostGIS geometry data type, not x and y coordinates.  This is simply changed to `ORDER BY ST_X(t1.geom)`.

Comment: I'll also have to do some optimization, since when ran on our full production data base the query is prohibitively slow (the database itself could use some optimization, honestly).  If you have any ideas on how to make this faster, I'm all ears, though I know it's out of the scope of this particular question.  Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Spatial index for `xyz_master`, but I'm sure you have that already. You could also put the result of the sub-query in a separate table and add a column which will contain `CEIL(t2.row_num / 1000.0)`. Index the geometry and that new row_num column. Call that table instead of having a sub-query